# function pointer incompatible pointer types void (*)(void *) from void (my_type *)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I'm having getting the above warning and understand it, but just don't know how to fix it. My code is below, but basically what I'm doing is storing a function pointer in a struct, and initializing the struct in another function that I call from my main. The code seems to compile when I use it with a default function (i.e. free()) but not when I use it with the test_func function below. Thoughts?

Struct:

```
  typedef struct my_struct {
  my_type **double_pointed;
  int num;
  void (*funcp)(void *data);
  } my_struct_t;
```

Init function:

```
my_struct_t *init(int num, void (*my_funcp)(void *data)) {

    // unimportant code to the problem, but basically just some mallocs for the other data

  my_struct_t *my_str;
  my_str->funcp = my_funcp;

  return struct;
}
```

function I want to point to:

```
void desired_func(my_type *obj) {}
```

my call to the init func:

```
init(5, desired_func);
```

full error:

incompatible pointer types assigning to 'void (*)(void *)' from
      'void (my_type *)'

on the line in the init function above:

```
my_struct_t *my_str;
my_str->funcp = my_funcp;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the function pointer types to match the function, ie. :

```
void (*funcp)(my_type *data);
```

If you want to be able to use functions with different signatures (eg. different parameter types), you can add explicit casts. For example :

```
init(5, (void (*)(void*)) desired_func);
```

Note that any time the `desired_func` function (or any other function whose signature doesn't match the `funcp` function pointer) needs to be called through the function pointer, the function pointer will have to be cast back to its original type (`void (*)(my_type*)` in this case) before calling the function, or it invokes undefined behavior.

Another (somewhat better) alternative is to change the `desired_func` definition like this :

```
void desired_func(void *vobj) {
    my_type* obj = vobj;
    /* rest of the code */
}
```

Note that when calling `desired_func` (through a function pointer or directly), the type of the object whose address is passed as parameter needs to be `my_type`, or dereferencing `obj` inside the function (and if alignment differs even the cast itself) will invoke undefined behavior.

The added complexity for dealing with the potential for undefined behavior when casting (as noted above) means that I would advise against casting - needing such casts is probably indicative of a problem in your design. Ie. there's probably a better solution if you think about your requirements a bit more.

Comment: The problem is that it has to operate on all datatypes, hence void*

Comment: @bobbyyu10 : I've addressed that as well now

Comment: Converting to and from `void *` doesn't require a cast, so `my_type *obj = vobj;` is sufficient.

Comment: Using (calling) a function pointer using the incorrect type will cause undefined behavior. Please amend the answer.

Comment: @2501 : I didn't mention that, since I wasn't actually using the function pointer in the code samples (and as I'm sure you know, the cast in itself is perfectly legal). But you're right that adding such warning is prudent, so I will. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: init probably doesn't call the function. *Anytime* the function is called via the member of my_struct_t it has to be of, or cast to, the correct type. The rest seems ok.

Comment: I think it would be best to put the better alternative at the start... except that the cast is unnecessary when converting between `void *` and other pointer-to-object types. Regarding the UB, you could trigger a warning with a bit of preprocessor abuse appended: `#define desired_func(value) do { mytype *v = value; desired_func(v); } while (0)`... Nice answer :)

Comment: ... or even an error with `#define desired_func(value) do { mytype v = *value; desired_func(value); } while (0)` hmmmm

Comment: @Seb : interesting macro's ! Upvoted your comments to increase visibility. About the unnecessary cast from `void*`, that's just a habit. Since you're the second person to point it out, and I don't feel strongly either way, I'll remove the cast.