# Why is storing a function with different argument type to function pointer with void* argument UB?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I recently stumbled across an interesting question (at least i think it is).
A little example:

## Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A {
    int x;
} A;

int (*func)(void*, void*);

int comp(A* a, A* b) {
    return a->x - b->x;
}

int main() {
    func = comp;
    A a;
    A b;
    a.x = 9;
    b.x = 34;
    printf("%d > %d ? %s\n", a.x, b.x, func(&a, &b) > 0 ? "true" : "false");
}
```

I asked myself if the above shown is valid code but on compilation GCC threw a warning: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`. I did some research and in one thread [someone stated the above would be undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474935/9232218) now im curious why this is UB since `void*` can be casted savely to any possible other type. Is it just the standard saying "Nope thats undefined" or is there some explainable reason? All questions on StackOverflow I found state its UB but not exactly why. Maybe it has something to do how a function pointer is dereferenced internally?

Comment: Casting any pointer type to `void` pointer is safe. Casting `void` pointer to any pointer type whose size is larger than 1 is not safe. Why? Because platform-dependent alignment restrictions are not guaranteed. For example, consider the case of casting a `void` pointer whose value is not divisible by `sizeof(int)` to an `int` pointer, on a platform (compiler and HW) which does not support unaligned load and store operations.

Comment: @goodvibration are you sure? Why is it save to use `malloc` then? It returns `void*` and does not need to be casted

Comment: @goodvibration Not correct.  Any pointer type can be safely converted to `void *` and back.  You just can't convert from one incompatible pointer type to another through a `void *`.

Comment: `malloc` allocates blocks aligned to the platform word-size (typically 32-bits or 64-bits). So you're always safe with this function.

Comment: @goodvibration ah okay so you are saying that in general casting `void*` to any other type is UB but we just have the luck to have almost every system support aligned pointers?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "support aligned pointers", but the alignment problem is due to the fact that some systems do not support load and store (read and write) operations to **unaligned** addresses. For example, suppose you have `char arr[100]`. Then trying to write a `int` value into different areas within that block will not necessarily "run smoothly". For example, if `*(int*)(arr+12) = 5` will work as you'd expect, then `*(int*)(arr+13) = 5` will not work as you'd expect, unless the underlying platform supports unaligned store operations.

Comment: The standard states that "A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer." So converting is not the problem with unalignes systems but actually creating one would be. Would it even be possible to create a C compiler for a system without alignes memory access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `void *` can be safely converted to/from any other type, but that's not the conversion you're trying to do.  You're trying to convert a `int (*)(A *, A *)` to a `int (*)(void *, void*)`.  Those are two very different things.

The automatic conversion of `void *` does not apply to the arguments in a function pointer.  For two function pointers to be compatible, the number and type of the arguments must be compatible as well as the return type.

One of the reasons for this is that a `void *` need not have the same representation as other types of pointers.  This is fine when simply converting to a `void *` and back which the standard explicitly allows, however it can be a problem when calling a function.

Suppose a `void *` is represented with 8 bytes and a struct pointer is represented with 4 bytes.  In your example, two 8 byte values would be pushed onto the stack but two 4 bytes values would be read from the stack as parameters in the function.  This would result in invalid pointer values which would be subsequently dereferenced.

Comment: Mh but is there a deeper explanation why this is not valid or is this then rather implementation wise? I mean the `C` standard propably states somewhere what a function pointer is and how it is treated so when the function is loaded what happens with the arguments when the function pointer has type `void*` and the actual function has type `MyObj` or something. How is a function pointer treated internally?

Comment: @Yastanub See my edit.  Different pointer types aren't necessarily represented the same.

Comment: Ah thank you very much so the reason is indeed that it is not guaranteed to have equal pointer sizes?

Answer (score 2):

*6.7.5.3  p15*

> For two  function  types  to  be  compatible,  both  shall  specify  compatible  return  types. Moreover,  the  parameter  type  lists,  if  both  are  present,  shall  agree  in  the  number  of parameters  and  in  use  of  the  ellipsis  terminator;  corresponding  parameters  shall  have compatible types.

The questions reduces recursively to whether `A*` is compatible with `void*`.

*6.7.5.1 p2*

> For two  pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

The type `A` is not compatible with `void`.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the standard excerpts. BTW where can i look them up if i want to research somethign like that again?

Comment: @Yastanub iso 9899

Comment: Whoa thanks i will definitely crawl through this :D

Answer (score 1):

As dbush and alinsoar have pointed out, the problem is that `int (*)(void *, void *)` and `int (*)(A *, A *)` are not compatible.  The way to fix this is to change the definition of `comp` as follows:

```
int comp( void *a, void *b )
{
  A *aa = a;
  A *bb = b;

  return aa->x - bb->x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i know how to resolve this :) It was more like a theoretical question as i wanted to know exactly why this is UB.